# AWS-SAM connecting to an existing Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, sam

I created one AWS sam server-less application
(created some Api's using python), I have a Mongo Db, I want it to be connected to the function.

But I don't know the procedure which I have to follow make it connected anyone please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can give the necessary permissions for your Lambda functions (and thus your serverless application) SAM templates.
You can follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sam-template-permissions/) guide in order to do that.

Comment: i managed to write some code above, but i got "Internal server error"

Comment: Did you check lambda cloudwatch logs ? what are the generated logs in addition to Internal server error ?

Comment: cloudwatch there is no error showing, i think the the query is not executing, i checked the query outside the app but its working